# Select only 1 from 2 tables when value is duplicate

Tags: sql

I have table information like this:

Table A:

```
001, YANDI, Jl damar
002, YAYA,  jl Selir
004, Nana , jl manggis
```

Table B:

```
003, maman, jl sehat
001, Yandi, jl damar
```

I want:

```
001, Yandi, jl damar
002, yaya,  jl selir
003, Maman, Jl sehat
004, Nana,  jl manggis
```

i am using

```
select distinct a.id, b.name from a as a join b as b on a.id= b.id
```

but does not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is not a free coding/homework service. You have to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: i'am using Distinc 
select distinct  a.id, b.name
from a as a
 join b as b
    on a.id= b.id 

but does not working sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM Table_3
UNION
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM Table_4;
```

'*' means "all columns" in the table will shown in the output.

If you want to display the specific field in the output, then

```
SELECT
  column_name1,
  column_name2,
  column_name3
FROM table_name;
```

In Sq-server,

this can be used to find difference between Table_A and Table_B

```
(   SELECT * FROM Table_A
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM Table_B)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT * FROM Table_B
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM Table_A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

The "union" forces the results to be unique. If you didn't want unique results then you'd use "union all".

Comment: if i want Select field but Different between a and B ??

Comment: @BataraYamadipati . . . Then you would have a different question.  New questions should be asked as *questions* and not as *comments*.  However, you can explicitly list the columns that you want for each `select`.